# PHP Script is correct, but not sending

Tags: php, contact-form

I am having difficulty with my php code. From my tired eyes, the code is correct, and I've had multiple others look at the code. No one can figure out why it's not working. It must be something quite simple, but I cannot get the contact form to send.

PHP script:

```
<?php


$from = 'email@example.com';
$sendTo = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');
$htmlHeader = '';
$htmlFooter = '';
$okMessage = 'Contact form succesfully submitted. Thank you, We will get back to you soon!';

$htmlContent = '<h1>New message from contact form</h1>';



use Nette\Mail\Message,
    Nette\Mail\SendmailMailer;


require 'php/Nette/nette.phar';


$configurator = new Nette\Configurator;
$configurator->setTempDirectory(__DIR__ . '/php/temp');
$container = $configurator->createContainer();


$httpRequest = $container->getService('httpRequest');
$httpResponse = $container->getService('httpResponse');

$post = $httpRequest->getPost();

if ($httpRequest->isAjax()) {

    $htmlContent .= '<table>';
    foreach ($post as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $htmlContent .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    $htmlContent .= '</table>';


    $htmlBody = $htmlHeader . $htmlContent . $htmlFooter;


    $mail = new Message;
    $mail->setFrom($from)
        ->addTo($sendTo)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($htmlBody, FALSE);

    $mailer = new SendmailMailer;
    $mailer->send($mail);


    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);

    $httpResponse->setCode(200);
    $response = new \Nette\Application\Responses\JsonResponse($responseArray);
    $response->send($httpRequest, $httpResponse);
}
```

Contact Form HTML:

```
<div class="section contact soepa" id="contact" data-animate="bounceIn">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">


            <h2 class="title"><span style="color: #f46b01;">Connect With Us</span></h2>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">

                        <div class="messages">

                        </div>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your firstname *" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Your lastname *" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email *" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your phone *" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message *" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: By default, Nette Mail uses the `mail()` function, which requires proper configuration under the `php.ini` file. Is it properly configured? http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: no error messages, Travis

Comment: Side note, you should maybe think about marking some of your questions as answered if they were the right answer. People may think twice about answering your questions if you never accept any answers.

Comment: Rasclatt. ok, thank you so much for the knowledge.